# Centering the content in my horizontal navigation bar (with the highlighting included)

Tags: html, css

So I made a navigation bar, but the only problem I'm having is centering the content in the navigation bar, while keeping it horizontal. So instead of the context starting on the left, it stays in the center.

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

li {
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

li a {
display: inline-block;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Ariel, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}
```

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: For me it is unclear what you want. Do you want the list elements to be centered in the unordered list?

Comment: I didn't explain it well. But yeah. To have the text start in the center of the margin, and stay horizontal

Comment: It would help if you included the html as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of float the list elements (floated elements can never be centered in their parent element) you have to use `display: inline-block;` for them and then just center the `ul`:

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The whole code would be:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
text-align: center;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
}

li a {
display: inline-block;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Ariel, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gye4vc8/)

Comment: Then please mark the answer as correct and it would be appreciate to receive an up vote for it. :)